# How receive link attributes of event in Backbone?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

I want to receive attributes in Backbone View of this link. I'm not sure this is right way to do this in Backbone. Maybe params of this link should be set on view rendering?

`<a class="postDeleteLink" data-id="5" data-hash="Hgsda45f">Delete</a>`

My Backbone code to bind an event:

```
PostListView = Backbone.View.extend({
events: {
    "click .postDeleteLink": "deletePost"
},
deletePost: function(){
    //standart jquery way doesn't work, because "this" is already used by backbone
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id'); 
    var hash = $(this).attr('data-hash'); 
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass the event to deletePost and access via currentTarget.

```
PostListView = Backbone.View.extend({
events: {
    "click .postDeleteLink": "deletePost"
},
deletePost: function(e){
    var id = $(e.currentTarget).attr('data-id'); 
    var hash = $(e.currentTarget).attr('data-hash'); 
}
```

Comment: Sounds like true! Can you add some code which shows how to pass it correctly via event?

Comment: @GediminasŠukys I have posted the code. If you notice the argument in the deletePost function, that is the event.

Comment: You can also say `$(e.currentTarget).data('id')` if you don't mind jQuery trying to infer the type of `data-id`.