# How to get attributes from the clicked element in backbone event?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

Here is my basic backbone view for changing routes. I would like to get the href attribute of the clicked link. How to do that? Here is a code bellow:

```
var Menu = Backbone.View.extend({   
        el: '.nav', 
        events: {
            'click a' : 'changeRoute'
        },  
        changeRoute: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            //var href = $(this).attr("href");
            router.navigate(href, true);
        }
 });
```

I am a newbie in backbone, so please have mercy :)

Comment: Same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13807243/how-receive-link-attributes-of-event-in-backbone/13807330#13807330

Answer (score 33, accepted):

you can use: `var element = $(e.currentTarget);`

then any attributes can be called like this: `element.attr('id')`

so in your code above:

```
changeRoute: function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var href = $(e.currentTarget).attr("href");
   router.navigate(href, true);
}
```